# Create materialized view with hierarchical query and ANSI join

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views, connect-by, hierarchical-query

I am unable to create a materialized view and getting a `ORA-904` error. This looks like the [Bug 17551261](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=17551261.8) , but this should already be fixed. I tested it on Oracle 12.2, 19 and 21.

In the view i use a connect by statement and ANSI join.
When i rewrite the ANSI join to Oracle join the error disappears.

To reproduce the error i created these sample tables:

```
create table example_type( id number(10) primary key, name varchar2(100 byte));

create table example( id number(10) primary key, name varchar2(100 byte), 
                      father_id number(10) references example(id), 
                      example_type_id  number(10) not null references example_type(id) );
```

With ANSI join:

```
create materialized view example_list_ansi_join( example_id, root_example_type, example_path)
  refresh on demand
as
  select e.id                                  example_id,
         connect_by_root(et.name)              root_example_type,
         sys_connect_by_path( e.name, ' > ')   example_path
    from example e
   inner join example_type et on et.id = e.example_type_id 
 connect by prior e.id = e.father_id
   start with father_id is null;
```

> Error:
>
> ORA-12018: following error encountered during code generation for "SQLLIVE"."EXAMPLE_LIST_ANSI_JOIN"
>
> ORA-00904: "from$_subquery$_013"."FATHER_ID_2": invalid identifier
>
> 12018.0000 -"following error encountered during code generation for "%s"."%s""
>
> *Cause:    The refresh operations for the indicated materialized view could not be regenerated due to errors.
>
> *Action:   Correct the problem indicated in the following error messages and repeat the operation.

with Oracle join:

```
create materialized view example_list_oracle_join( example_id, root_example_type, example_path)
  refresh on demand
as
  select e.id                               example_id,
         connect_by_root(et.name)           root_example_type,
         sys_connect_by_path(e.name,' > ')  example_path
    from example       e,
         example_type  et
   where et.id = e.example_type_id 
 connect by prior e.id = e.father_id
   start with e.father_id is null;
```

> No error:
>
> Materialized view EXAMPLE_LIST_ORACLE_JOIN created.

Is this still a bug?

Comment: It certainly sounds similar. Only Oracle Support can say for sure if it is the same problem.

Comment: There seems to be quite a number of bugs, for instance 27706670 (Doc ID 27706670.8). I'm not sure if Oracle Support is tracking the problem you describe.